# Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response') while using python

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-requests

Hello I am attempting to reach `https://api.louisvuitton.com/api/eng-us/catalog/availability/M80016`  through a session while using request in python. Currently I am unable to reach it and get an error of ***Remote end closed connection without response***.
I have been trying to debug but havent been successful. Bellow is my code and the output.

Code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://us.louisvuitton.com/eng-us/products/pocket-organizer-damier-graphite-nvprod2630093v#N60432",headers=headers)

if r:
    print("Requested Successfully")
else:
    print("Request Failed ==> " + str(r))
    exit()

url2 = "https://api.qubit.com/graphql"

payload = json.dumps({
  "query": "query ($trackingId: String!, $contextId: String!) {\n property(trackingId: $trackingId) {\n   visitor(contextId: $contextId) {\n     ipAddress\n     ipLocation: location {\n       city\n       cityCode\n       country\n       countryCode\n       latitude\n       longitude\n       area\n       areaCode\n       region\n       regionCode\n     }\n     segment: segments {\n       state\n     }\n     history {\n       conversionCycleNumber: conversionCycle\n       conversionNumber: conversions\n       entranceNumber: entrances\n       firstConversionTs: firstConversion\n       firstViewTs: firstView\n       lastConversionTs: lastConversion\n       lastViewTs: lastView\n       lifetimeValue\n       sessionNumber: sessions\n       viewNumber: views\n     }\n   }\n }\n}",
  "variables": {
   "trackingId": "louisvuitton_prod",
   "contextId": "o6vfrf9jm4g-0k999shdp-fiadwa4"
  }})

headers2 = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }

x = s.post(url2,headers=headers2, data=payload)

if x:
    print("Post Successfully")
else:
    print("Post Failed ==> " + str(x))
    exit()

 
headers3 = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)',
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Host': "api.louisvuitton.com",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

cookies = s.cookies

t = s.get("https://api.louisvuitton.com/api/eng-us/catalog/availability/M80016",headers=headers3,cookies=cookies)

if t:
    print("Get Successfully")
else:
    print("Get Failed ==> " + str(t))
    exit()
```

Output

```
Requested Successfully
Post Successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3-1.25.10-py3.8.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3-1.25.10-py3.8.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3-1.25.10-py3.8.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Anyone have a clue or idea how to resolve this issues? Would appreciated any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the cookies on the webpage in Chrome with `Inspect Element` -> `application` -> `storage` -> `cookies` -> https://us.louisvuitton.com/ you see about 40 cookies. However if you add `import pprint` to your code and at line 50 `pprint.pprint(s.cookies.get_dict())` you see only 4 cookies. So you are missing many cookies.

The response you get is actually an Access Denied message as you can see if you use `Inspect Element` -> `Network` copy as cURL on the https://api.louisvuitton.com/api/eng-us/catalog/availability/nvprod... URL and remove the cookies except for your 4 and run it, if you run it will all the cookies it works fine.

So as there are many XHR requests than can set cookies I suggest you either go through all requests decode them if needed and read all the JavaScript files to see if they set cookies or a much easier solution use Selenium, requests-html https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/ or PyQT